# Why does my AVL-Insertion return segmentation fault after a large input?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

I am implementing the avl tree structure. When i run the insertion operation, I see a strange thing happen: if the input is small enough, i.e. 10 or 20, then the insertion runs fine. Once I try to insert 100 elements then everything goes to a seg fault and no matter what I do, it does not run correctly afterwards.

I have tried lots of advice from this site and my own debugging/tracing on paper, can't seem to catch the error.

This is my insertion operation:

```
Node *AVLTree::insert(Node *node, int key)
{
    /*
    insert a node into a binary tree.
    */
    if (node == NIL)
    {
        return (newNode(key)); // O(1)
    }
    if (key < node->val)
    {
        node->left = this->insert(node->left, key); // T(n/2)
        node->left->p = node;
    }
    else if (key > node->val)
    {
        node->right = this->insert(node->right, key); // T(n/2)
        node->right->p = node;
    }
    else
    {
        return node;
    }
    node->height = 1 + fmax(height(node->left), height(node->right)); // O(i log i) where i is the number of nodes in the current subtree
    int balance = this->get_balance(node);                            // O(1)
    if (balance > 1 && node->left != NIL && key < node->left->val)
    {
        return this->right_rotate(node); // O(1)
    }
    if (balance > 1 && node->left != NIL && key > node->left->val)
    {
        node->left = this->left_rotate(node->left);
        return this->right_rotate(node); // O(1)
    }
    if (balance < -1 && node->right != NIL && key > node->right->val)
    {
        return this->left_rotate(node); // O(1)
    }
    if (balance < -1 && node->right != NIL && key < node->right->val)
    {
        node->right = this->right_rotate(node->right);
        return this->left_rotate(node); // O(1)
    }
    return node;
}
```

These are left and right rotations

```
Node *AVLTree::left_rotate(Node *x)
{
    Node *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if (y->left != NIL)
    {
        y->left->p = x;
    }
    y->p = x->p;
    if (x->p == NIL)
    {
        this->root = y;
    }
    else if (x == x->p->left)
    {
        x->p->left = y;
    }
    else
    {
        x->p->right = y;
    }
    y->left = x;
    x->p = y;
    x->height = 1 + fmax(height(x->left), height(x->right));
    y->height = 1 + fmax(height(y->left), height(y->right));
    return y;
}

Node *AVLTree::right_rotate(Node *y)
{
    Node *x = y->left;
    y->left = x->right;
    if (x->right != NIL)
    {
        x->right->p = y;
    }
    x->p = y->p;
    if (y->p == NIL)
    {
        this->root = x;
    }
    else if (y == y->p->left)
    {
        y->p->left = x;
    }
    else
    {
        y->p->right = x;
    }
    x->right = y;
    y->p = x;
    x->height = 1 + fmax(height(x->left), height(x->right));
    y->height = 1 + fmax(height(y->left), height(y->right));
    return x;
}
```

my main code is below

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> A = create_random_data(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3])); // creates a vector of size argv[1] with random ints between argv[2] and argv[3]
    Node *root = NIL;

    AVLTree tree = AVLTree(root);
    display(A); // displays input array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        tree.root = tree.insert(tree.root, A[i]);
    }
}
```

Error occurs in the insertion loop and I tried to trace where exactly but it's hard to tell. Thanks for any recommendation/advice!

Comment: Might not be related, but the use of `fmax` stands out as not the right tool. A tree is a discrete structure, you should use integers all around.

Comment: "`if (node == NIL)`" - really? `NIL`? Don't you mean `NULL` or `0` or (better) `nullptr`?

Comment: Advice -- Don't start out with random data.  If your tree has an issue, you want to isolate the data set that causes the issue.  Introducing random data just moves the target, making it harder to debug.  Just hardcode the input data into the program -- not only will it make it more easier to debug, you could actually post a [mcve] with the test data, instead of us having to guess.

Comment: Also - `Once I try to insert 100` -- Chances are the issues exist when you insert a fewer number of elements, just that the error isn't exposed until you reach 100.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I used `#define` to create a `NIL`, just got used to it for some reason.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I followed your recommendation and it seems that the random generator was causing the issue. Now the program works.